# Displaying different Django forms at different template locations

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a model like this:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
```

Example instances of this model are:

```
Foo.objects.create(text="My first text [[@shorttext_1@]] random text.")
Foo.objects.create(text="Select something from below [[@multipleselect_1@]]. text.")
Foo.objects.create(text="A different form [[@shorttext_1@]] and another" 
                        "form [[@shorttext_2@]] random texts.")
Foo.objects.create(text="Mixed form [[@shorttext_1@]] and another" 
                        "form [[@multipleselect_1@]] random text.")
```

The values `[[@shorttext_1@]]`, `[[@multipleselect_1@]]` represent the location and the type of the forms to be placed in the template below. `[[@ @]]` is a randomly chosen markdown style placeholder.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class ShortTextForm(forms.Form):  # [[@shorttext_1@]] form
    short_text = forms.CharField(max_length=300)

class MultipleSelectionForm(forms.Form): # [[@multipleselect_1@]] form
    selection = forms.ChoiceField( 
        choices=[('A', 'A text'), ('B', 'B text')], 
        widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def text_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # get the info for each form
    else:
        foo = Foo.objects.order_by('?').first()
        return render(
            request=request,
            template_name='templates/index.html',
            context={'text': foo.text})
```

**templates/index.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body %}
    {{ text }}
{% endblock %}
```

Is it possible to show the `foo.text` in template and render the desired forms?

Currently, I have a `type` variable in my `Foo` class to designate the type of the form. And my view can render only one desired type of form which can only placed at the end of the text. I want to render multiple forms at any location of the text using only one template.

EDIT:

To give an example output of I want to achieve:

```
Foo.objects.create(text="The age of the person is [[@shorttext_1@]] and "
                        "another attribute is [[@shorttext_2@]]. "
                        "Additionally select one:<br>[[@multipleselect_1@]]")
```

this object should be rendered in the template such that the output looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Just pass foo:

```
context={'foo': foo}
```

not foo.text and use `if...else` statements inside your template to figure out what you want to do.

This will let you access the `type` variable too:

```
{% if foo.type == some_type %}
    {{ form }}
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: This method will not allow me to put multiple forms in designated places. Using this method how am I possibly put two different forms in the following text `"Mixed form [[@shorttext_1@]] and another form [[@multipleselect_1@]] random text."`?